# Need access to request object inside of a Configuration file in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5.5

I'm starting a migration from Laravel 4.2 to Laravel 5.5 and am starting with my customized config files.

One of my config files needs to know the request method being used (GET,POST,DELETE,PUT) and in laravel 4.2 I just simple used this command:

```
if (Request::isMethod('POST')) {
   * do stuff *
}
```

In Laravel 5.5, it throws an error:

> Class 'Request' not found {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'Request' not found at /vagrant/config/api.php:8)

I added:

> use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Then tried changing the code to:

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
   * do stuff *
}
```

and then I get this:

> Call to a member function method() on null {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function method() on null at /vagrant/config/api.php:4)

I also tried putting use Illuminate\Http\Request into the default controller, thinking that it's likely I can't put the use statement in the config file, but still no joy.

Can anyone give me a hand?

Here is an example of the config file:

```
if (Request::isMethod('POST')) {
    $methodArray = [
                    'endpoint1' => [
                        'param1' => 'value1',
                        'param2' => 'value2',
                      ]
                   ],[
                    'endpoint2' => [
                        'param1' => 'value1',
                        'param2' => 'value2',
                      ]
                   ];
} else if (Request::isMethod('GET')) {
    $methodArray = [
                    'endpoint3' => [
                        'param1' => 'value1',
                        'param2' => 'value2',
                      ]
                   ],[
                    'endpoint4' => [
                        'param1' => 'value1',
                        'param2' => 'value2',
                      ]
                   ];
}
```

Comment: On laravel 5.5 you can create resource controller that have methods for all this requests

Comment: Do you by chance have a link for how to do this?  The changes from 4.2 to 5.5 are a little more extensive than I realized.  I'm interested in what you are saying, but I really just need to know how to access the request object inside the config file.

Comment: I know that it will be hard to recode 4.2 to this controller, but i think it will be great for application. Here you have resource controller example for 5.5 https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: I found that link a few minutes ago and was reading up on it.  Essentially I am setting arrays of data for each type of method request that is used for some security stuff.  I'm not sure I see how a resource controller is going to work for what I need to do here.

Is there no way to get the request method inside of a config file in 5.5?

Comment: Can you showu your config file ?

Comment: An example of the config file has been added to the original question as it seems I can't add code snippets in the comment section.

Comment: I think you can load config items dependence on request method that you can check in controller, so for examlple you can load `if($request->isMethod('POST')) { $postarray = configfile['post']  }` and then you have all endpoint in variable.